# React remix api route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix, remix.run

How to create an api route which is inside a api folder. I want to separte my view and api files. Here api>users.js (api/users) is not working. But if i create a file name api.users.js (api/users) inside routes it works and also the api>index.js (/api). I need to keep my api files in a folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix `v2` *flat files* convention prevents you from using folders for nested routes. It only supports folders for colocation.

You can switch back to the `v1` convention using the package `@remix-run/v1-route-convention`

https://github.com/remix-run/v1-compat-utils/tree/main/packages/v1-route-convention